Quickjs and localisation, is it possible to polyfill?
I'm using quickjs via quickjs-emscripten. I've noticed that localisation functions such as Number(10000).toLocaleString('en-US') don't work, this gives 10000 instead of 10,000
I haven't had any luck polyfilling this with the intl package yet.

I was able to polyfill using the fastly polyfil service here https://polyfill-fastly.io/
Select all the Intl packages and also include locales that you need ( i.e. Intl.~locale.en )
Save the result to a file and then module load that into quickjs.
